# Unpack a list of nested dictionaries and convert to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to write to CSV a JSON that produces a list of nested dictionnaries as follows:

```
[{'spam': 'xxxx',
  'egg': 'yyyy',
  'line_items': [{'description': 'hhh',
                  'amount': 'iii'},
                 {'description': 'jjj',
                  'amount': 'kkk'}],
  'bacon': 'zzzz'}]
```

I wrote the following code (being still very new to Python):

```
import csv

jsonData = json.loads(r.text)
keys = list(jsonData[0].keys())
with open(filePathCsv, 'w') as csvfile:
    w = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(jsonData)
```

This produces the following:

[CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvTG4.png)

What I need to achieve is this:

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfHD.png)

where each nested line item produces a new row.

I imagine the best way to achieve this is to unpack my list of nested dictionnaries to a simple list of dictionnaries, like so:

```
[{'spam': 'xxxx',
  'egg': 'yyyy',
  'description': 'hhh',
  'amount': 'iii',
  'bacon': 'zzzz'},
 {'spam': 'xxxx',
    'egg': 'yyyy',
    'description': 'jjj',
    'amount': 'kkk',
    'bacon': 'zzzz'}]
```

But I am at a loss as to how to achieve this.

Or perhaps there is another way to achieve my expected result?

Comment: So was your question resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or perhaps there is another way to achieve my expected result?

If you use `pandas`, there's a one-liner for this, using `json_normalize`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'spam': 'xxxx',
  'egg': 'yyyy',
  'line_items': [{'description': 'hhh',
                  'amount': 'iii'},
                 {'description': 'jjj',
                  'amount': 'kkk'}],
  'bacon': 'zzzz'}]

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path=['line_items'],
                                meta=['spam', 'egg','bacon'])
df

  amount description   egg  spam bacon
0    iii         hhh  yyyy  xxxx  zzzz
1    kkk         jjj  yyyy  xxxx  zzzz
```

---

```
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED ! It works indeed! You saved me a few grey hairs! Subsequent question, if permitted: some of the other fields have a dictionary, like so:
 {'spam': {'match': '139442'},
  'bacon': {'formatted': '2017-08-26'},
  'egg': {'iso8601': '2017-08-29', 'match': '29-AUG-17'}
Is there a way to just extract the/one value from the dict to be assigned to 'spam', 'bacon' and 'egg'?
I have gone through the pandas DataFrame doc but couldn't find anything.
In any case, thanks again!!